# Edit column inside column inside table_name?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, database

So i need help i am creating a game and the sql list creates a username and password and i want to store the wood,stone,steel data into the database under the correct username but i don't know how.

[image: database]

its like that but the only code i know is:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET column = newdata");
```

but here is the error it won't create it because there is no such column named column, i need it to search for the username and then insert the wood data into the wood data space.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 

$wood= "document.getElementById('wood').value";
$stone= "document.getElementById('stone').value";
$steel= "document.getElementById('steel').value";

mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET `wood` = $wood WHERE `username`=$myusername");
mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET `stone` = $stone WHERE `username`=$myusername");
mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET `steel` = $steel WHERE `username`=$myusername");
?>
```

Comment: You want to add a new column?

Comment: No i already have the column i just need to know how to enter data into wood under the username user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table_name` SET `wood` = 12 WHERE `username`='user'");
```

Comment: question why does wood = 12?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table_name` SET `wood` = 12 WHERE `id`=1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix user information and metadata in a single table. You can separate user name/password and other information by separating in two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `active` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `data` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `wood` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `stone` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `steel` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then, you can do

```
$wood = mysql_real_escape_string( 'wood info' );
$stone = mysql_real_escape_string( 'stone info' );
$steel = mysql_real_escape_string( 'steel info' );
$userid = 'ID of the user against which you want to update.';

mysql_query("UPDATE `data` SET `wood`=$wood, `stone`=$stone, `steel`=$steel WHERE `user_id`=$userid;");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have this code to read the string within the span will it work?


$wood= "document.getElementById('wood').value";

Comment: Thanks and yeah its not updating, staying at 0 on the mysql database

Comment: Oh! I thought you were using it in `javascript`. I guess you are trying to access in PHP. The it will be `$wood=$_POST['wood']`. I am assuming you are using `POST` method in your form and the textbox/editbox is named `wood`. Would be able to help more if you show me the html.

Comment: yeah sorry i'm not using post i haven't learnt that i'm just using <span id="wood">1000</span> then i fetch it but i'm having trouble trying to fetch the text inside the span.

Comment: so thats the building file main window and that has the resource timer and i have posted the php that i need to get the data from the spans from and how i tried.